# Should I split my SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql

I have a table where the majority of columns are very, very often read (SELECTed) and are almost never updated.

I now need to add a set of columns to the same table (they are properties of the same entity), only these will be less often read, and also very often updated

If I add the new columns into the same table, will the UPDATEs interfere with the  SELECTs?

Should I instead create a new table with a 1-to-1 relationship to the previous table?

If it matters I am using Azure SQL Server.

Comment: What does often mean in numbers?

Comment: The main fields are read thousand of times an hour, in different complex queries, and are almost never updated. The new fields will be read hundreds of times an hour and will be updated hundreds of times an hour

Comment: Since there is a difference in usage of the fields, I would guess that they are somehow related differently to the main key. A separate table to store this information is no vice, probably even a good idea. If you get the impression that you are getting a lot of columns in a table, it is time to normalize it (or normalize it further).

Comment: Thousands an hour is not a lot.  I would not pre-optimize.

Comment: Do indexes need to be updated? Do some apply to the nominally read-only columns? Do you keep the index statistics current? Could some queries be satisfied from only the nominally read-only columns? As Paparazzi suggests, avoid [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/). If you don't have a _measurable_ performance issue, how do you plan to optimize the system?

Comment: While it is only thousands of time an hour. The queries involved are very complex, ranging from seconds to tens of seconds. I am not at the stage where i MUST optimize or die, but the load is felt, i would rather optimize in advance and reduce impact where i can

Comment: For access patterns you describe, vertical partitioning is a very good idea. The only drawback is a little extra database space, while advantages are many. And it's not a premature optimisation, since access patterns are already known.

Comment: Any optimization that make structure more complex in order to address a potential issue is premature. The overall usage described in the question is not necessarily very stressing for the database. We don't even know if the complex queries translate into complex execution. I say - do proper schema adjustment and have backup plan in place if you are really worried.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, splitting things out into separate tables is never a bad idea. However, in this case it shouldn't matter. The `UPDATE` statements will not interfere with the `SELECT`s unless the `SELECT` statements are selecting the columns to be updates (which it sounds like, since these are new columns your adding, would not be the case unless the select statements are `SELECT *` ). In other words, if your SELECT statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT distinct * FROM my.Table where [NewColumn] is not NULL
```

In this case it may depend on when the UPDATE statement was run because if we assume the new column(s) are null by default and the UPDATE statement updates the first row, then the `SELECT` statement runs before it updates the next row, you could end up selecting only 1 row when you meant to select 2 rows.

Based on how you've described the table, it sounds to me like your better off splitting things up even though it is very unlikely that the statements would interfere with each other.